# Fine-Uploader: fail to load a thumbnail from the server

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I want to draw a thumbnail genenerated by my server after successful uploading.

My code:

```
function createUploader() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('uploader_button'),
        multiple: false,
        display: {
            fileSizeOnSubmit: true
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '/upload/newDocument',
            params: {
                token: '********'
            }
        },

        /* ...settings... */

        callbacks: {
            onComplete: updatePicture
        }
    });

    function updatePicture() {
        uploader.drawThumbnail(document.getElementById('picture'), 200, true);
    };
};
```

Html:

```
<img id="picture" src="/preview/empty.jpg" class="qq-thumbnail-selector">
```

Server response:

```
{"success":true,"thumbnailUrl":"\/preview\/00a64818c21a35ab59a342cc3e41182e50c06fa3528b128db22bb0.33508816.jpg"}
```

Fine-Uploader log output:

```
[FineUploader 4.0.3] xhr - server response received for 0 fineuploader-4.0.3.min.js:16
[FineUploader 4.0.3] responseText = {"success":true,"thumbnailUrl":"\/preview\/00a64818c21a35ab59a342cc3e41182e50c06fa3528b128db22bb0.33508816.jpg"} fineuploader-4.0.3.min.js:16
[FineUploader 4.0.3] Received response status 200 with body: {"success":true,"thumbnailUrl":"\/preview\/00a64818c21a35ab59a342cc3e41182e50c06fa3528b128db22bb0.33508816.jpg"} fineuploader-4.0.3.min.js:16
```

`updatePicture` function invokes successfully after uploading, but no thumbnail is drawn.

What is wrong in my code? What should I do to draw a thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the `drawThumbnail` method correctly.  Per the [documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html), the first parameter is the ID of the associated file.  So, your onComplete callback should look like this:

```
onComplete: function(id) {
    updatePicture(id)
}
```

and your updatePicture function must be changed to:

```
function updatePicture(fileId) {
    uploader.drawThumbnail(fileId, document.getElementById('picture'), 200, true);    
}
```